# No internet connection with Static IP; Ubuntu Server 22.04 LTS

Tags: networking, server, virtualbox, 22.04, static-ip

I'm newbie.
I'm learning to hosting a server using Ubuntu (I wandered around and found that it's best for server hosting)

I'm using Ubuntu Server 22.04 LTS, Oracle VBOX 6.1.36

I'm using `Bridged Adapter` in Vbox and have assigned static IP to my server using examples section in `netplan.io`. I modified `/etc/netplan/00-installer-config.yaml`. But the problem is that after assigning Static IP, I lose network and can't download anything, can't ping any website etc.

Here are the settings :

```
network:
  version: 2
  renderer: networkd
  ethernets:
    enp3s0:
      addresses:
        - 192.168.0.101/24
      nameservers:
        addresses: [8.8.8.8, 8.8.4.4]
      routes:
        - to: default
          via: 192.168.0.1
```

`192.168.0.1` is my router address.
After this, I do `sudo reboot` and after rebooting I do `ip a` and `ifconfig` and [this is what I get](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nUdMN.png).

I've tried ALL tutorial and forums but not helpful. And most of them are from older versions.

Can someone help? Thanks.

---

Is it possible to setup a server using NAT in Vbox? *(I heard that using NAT is more secure than Bridged as it separates host and VM)*

When using Bridged Adapter, I can access the `.html` file of `apache2` from my host device (windows). But when using NAT, which gives `10.0.2.15` ip address, I can't.

IF it is possible to access, how do I do it?

Currently I'm learning to host nextcloud,and hosting website.

Any other recommendation/suggestions are much appreciated.

Answer (score 2):

### Server status

Your settings are obviously incorrect because the `ip a` command does not display any active interface except loopback lo. Therefore, the server cannot communicate. The enp0s3 interface has a DOWN flag and its address is not set at all.

### Checks

Try the following:

Look at the original contents of the `/etc/netplan/*.yaml` file before you changed it. If it contains line `renderer: NetworkManager`, then the server is using NetworkManager and the settings you made in `/etc/netplan/xxxx.yaml` will not work. Instead, you need to change the file in the `/etc/NetworkManager/system-connections` directory. See below the **Repairing of the NetworkManager** and **NetworkManager setting**.

Check the status of the network service:

```
sudo systemctl status systemd-networkd
sudo systemctl status network-manager
```

Which of two services is running? **Only one of them should be alive.** If none, then you need to activate systemd-networkd.

```
sudo systemctl start systemd-networkd
```

When the service is not starting, use the logs to find out why it crashes.

If the start was successful and the network is working, use the `enable` clause to make the service active after the system starts.

```
sudo systemctl enable systemd-networkd
```

### Repairing of the NetworkManager

Make these changes only if you find that the `network-manager` service is active and `systemd-networkd` is inactive.

1. Return the server to its original settings in `/etc/netplan/00-installer-config.yaml` and other places where you made edits.
2. Restart the Ubuntu server. It should obtain an address from the DHCP server and start communicating normally over the network.

Use the `nmcli` command. Also view the contents of the files in the `/etc/NetworkManager/system-connections` directory.

Example of nmcli response if the system uses NetworkManager and the interface is live:

```
        "Intel I211"
        ethernet (igb), A8:A1:59:51:AB:CD, hw, mtu 1500
        ip4 default, ip6 default
        inet4 10.1.1.111/24
        route4 0.0.0.0/0
        route4 10.1.1.0/24
        ...
DNS configuration:
        servers: 10.1.1.1
        domains: lan
        interface: eth0
```

Example of the contents of the settings file in the `/etc/NetworkManager/system-connections` directory at a dynamic address from a DHCP server:

```
[connection]
id=Wired_connection_1
uuid=223088bf-66e3-3bc6-a0b8-52dc3707dd07
type=ethernet
autoconnect-priority=-999
interface-name=eth0
permissions=
timestamp=1659653519

[ethernet]
mac-address-blacklist=

[ipv4]
dns-search=lan;
method=auto
...
```

### NetworkManager setting

You need to make a change to the file in `/etc/NetworkManager/system-connections`.

Example of the contents of the `/etc/NetworkManager/system-connections/*.nmconnection` file for a manually entered IP address:

```
[connection]
id=Wired_connection_1
uuid=223088bf-66e3-3bc6-a0b8-52dc3707dd07
type=ethernet
autoconnect-priority=-999
interface-name=eth0
permissions=
timestamp=1659656501

[ethernet]
mac-address-blacklist=

[ipv4]
address1=10.1.1.160/24,10.1.1.1
dns=10.1.1.1;
dns-search=lan;
ignore-auto-dns=true
method=manual
```